# Spotify Player throwing ambiguous error when trying to play song

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am trying to play a song with the Spotify API, I have spotify permium but when I try to run the code below I get the error `Optional(Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=1 "The operation failed due to an unspecified issue." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation failed due to an unspecified issue.})`

```
func initalizePlayer(authSession: SPTSession) {
        if self.player == nil {
            self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
            self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
            self.player?.delegate = self
            try! player!.start(withClientId: clientId)
            self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
            print("done initalizing")
        }
    }

    public func play() {
        player?.playSpotifyURI("spotify:track:7FOJvA3PxiIU0DN3JjQ7jT", startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? Same issue, same exact code

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? I have the same issue